# Please Check the proof ,Reference-Real Analysis by HL Royden,3rd edition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> We define the integration with respect to a signed measure $\nu$ by
> defining $\int f d\nu=\int f d{\nu}^+-\int f d{\nu}^-$.
>
> If $\vert f\vert\le M,$ then prove that $\vert\int_E f d\nu\vert\le
>  \vert M\vert(E).$ Moreover,there is a measurable function $f$ with
> $\vert f\vert\le 1$ such that $\int_E fd\nu=\vert \nu\vert E$

Proof:$\vert\int_Efd\nu\vert=\vert\int_E fd\nu^+-\int_Efd\nu^-\vert\le\vert \int _Efd\nu^+ \vert+\int _Efd\nu^- \vert\le\int_E\vert f\vert d\nu^++\int_E\vert f\vert d\nu^-\le\int_EMd\nu^
++\int_E Md\nu^-= 
M\int_E d\nu^++M\int_Ed\nu^-=M\nu^+(E)+M\nu^-(E)=M(\nu^++\nu^-)(E)=M\vert \nu\vert(E)$

**Moreover part**

Assume the result,Move backwards $$\int_E fd\nu=\vert\nu\vert(E)$$
$$\implies \int_E fd\nu^+-\int_E fd\nu^-=\nu^+(E)+\nu^-(E)\tag{1}$$

$$\implies \int_E fd\nu^+=\nu^+(E),-\int_E fd\nu^-=\nu^-(E)\tag{2}$$

Let {P,N} be the Hahn Decomposition of the parent space
$$\implies \int_E fd\nu^+=\nu(E\cap P),\int_E fd\nu^-=-\nu^-(E)=\nu(E\cap N)\tag{3}$$

*What choice of $f$ can work satisfying above equations (3) and $\vert f \vert\le 1$?*

$f=1$ satisfies $\int_E fd\nu^+=\nu(E\cap P)=\nu^+(E)$ and

$f=-1$ satisfies $\int_E fd\nu^-=\nu(E\cap P)=-\nu^-(E)=\nu(E\cap N)$

$f =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{on P} \\[2ex]
-1, & \text{on N}
\end{cases}$

So,$\vert f\vert\le1$ and satisfies both equations (3)

**Doubts**

> (1)is the transition from equation 1 to equation 2 is correct?
>
> (2)$\vert f\vert\le 1$ can take values between -1 and 1,but here the $f$
> is taking only two values,where is the catch?